# JasperReports: How to make a dynamic report with multiple columns and rows

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm looking for help in making a report in *JasperReports*, the report format is something like an excel file where the rows and columns are both coming from the data. Even the column headers.

The report format is something like this.

```
    |Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 | Column9 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
row1| data1  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
row2|        |         | data2   |         |         |         |         |         |         |
row3| data3  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
```

and so on.

The data source used is XMLDataSource.

Comment: download some tool like iReportDesigner or Jasper Studio and follow some tutorial

Comment: @nobalG   Yes, I am using iReportDesigner to make the reports.

Comment: Then what's the problem you are facing?Just follow some tutorial and try your hands :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamicaly create JasperDesign object with and set page size. It will be your template. and add to it your columns dynamically. For example here I am add text field in runtime.

```
    textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setBlankWhenNull(true);
    textField.setX(120);
    textField.setY(0);
    textField.setWidth(145);
    textField.setHeight(30);
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.CENTER);
    textField.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignEnum.MIDDLE);
    textField.setStyle(jasperDesign.getStylesMap().get("Sans_Bold"));
    textField.setStretchType(StretchTypeEnum.RELATIVE_TO_BAND_HEIGHT);
    textField.setExpression(new JRDesignExpression("$P{UniqueNumberValue}"));
    JRLineBox lineBox = textField.getLineBox();
    lineBox.getPen().setLineWidth(Float.MIN_NORMAL);
    lineBox.getPen().setLineColor(Color.BLACK);
    band.addElement(textField);
```

Comment: Is there a place where I can find the documentation for these classes?

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer, since it gave me a headstart in the right direction.